# Chrome error on localhost

Tags: google-chrome, wampserver, shadow

I get the following an error while I work on localhost with Chrome. I get this error even if the page is empty:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of undefined
>       at lstr.js:26

(lstr.js is Chrome file)

Error line:

[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7lU3.jpg)

And I don't know if it's related to this, but there's a tag called shadow on console:

[image: thumbnail linked to main image]

I am not getting an error while I work with another browser. I use wampserver and this error is repeating when I use ajax. How can I eliminate this error?

Comment: Please provide the code in your question so we can better help you.

Comment: @Gideon I added to error line

Comment: Looks like it's not your code but something out of a Chrome Extension. You probably just need to disable/remove some to find out which one is causing it. If you run your page in a new Chrome Profile, it probably won't error.

Comment: @Gideon I wish you could answer. I found the incorrect attachment, thank you :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I faced the same issue on my console as well. Removing the chrome plugin [makegif-video-capture](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/makegif-video-capture/cnhdjbfjheoohmhpakglckehdcgfffbl?hl=en) fixed the issue. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks man you save my life to write lot of code to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of chrome extension.remove makegif-video-capture fixed the issue